# JavaScript RegExp test returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

I am solving curious problem right now. I am testing a string with regexp and it returns false eventhough it should return true. I am implementing it in javascript. I have this function

```
function isPhoneNumberValid(phoneNumber) {
  return /^\+\d{12}$/.test(phoneNumber);
}
```

`phoneNumber` is a variable in format of + and 12 numbers after (+421123123123 for example). I've played around with different versions of regexp like `/^\+[0-9]{12}$/`.

According to sites like https://www.regextester.com/21 my regexp should be working for the format I want, yet it returns false still. When I tried testing this regexp `/^\+[0-9]/` it returned true when only `+3` was written, I guess the problem is with the numbers count?

Parameter `phoneNumber` received in the function is correct one so I don't think the mistake is there. Also no combination of modifiers helped.

Here is a log of this function

```
function isPhoneNumberValid(phoneNumber) {
    console.log('ph:'+phoneNumber);
    console.log(/^\+\d{12}$/.test(phoneNumber));
}
```

[image]

To give you more insight I have a input type text with class `.phoneNumber`, then I have jquery function watching keyup event, it looks like this

```
$('.phoneNumber').on('keyup', function() {
    if (isPhoneNumberValid($(this).val())) {
        console.log('is valid');
    } else {
        console.log( 'invalid');
    }
});
```

Other function you've already seen above. I tried wrapping values in `String()`, too.

I am trying to clarify why live example in online environment is for no good, since I know this code works in there as I already stated before. The question is aimed more to what could possibly make it go this way, since the exact same copy works in codepen, yet doesn't work in my project.

Comment: /^\+\d{`min`,12}$/.test(phoneNumber)  replace min with the value you want to allow to be minimum string length

Comment: Your regex is matching exact of 12 digits, @DeepakKumarTP 's solution should be perfect!!!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gixicavase/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tried this rightaway. Unfortunately same result. Still gives me false.

Comment: Please conform the input should not contain the trailing space beginning spaces.

Comment: Are you SURE that you are sending in the phone number as a string (which preserves the `+`), and not as an integer (which does not preserve the `+`)?

Comment: You need to provide a real [mcve]. That should show your input, not just pictures of the output and one JS function.

Comment: Make a test: remove `^` and `$`. If you get true, there are some trailing/leading invisible characters in the input.

Comment: I removed `^` and `$` and it still gives me false. I am going to edit the question in a bit to give you more information

Comment: Add `phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/[^\d\+]/g,"")` before `return` the value

Comment: Re edit: Please provide a real [mcve]. Use the Stack Snippet functionality. If you just show us fragments of code, then everyone helping you has to build their own test case and guess at the bits you left out.

Comment: Case in point: http://jsbin.com/boguxiwede/1/edit?html,js,console,output — I still can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew — `$(this).val()` gives the whole value of the input element.

Comment: The problem is, that if I tried to copy the exact same code I have in my editor to for example codepen.io it works fine. That's why it's bothering me so much

Comment: I've tested your regex in developer console - it works  just fine. Problem is somewhere else, not in regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with latte template engine. It needed to have

```
<script n:syntax="double"></script>
```

to work.